# Contact form 7 before_send_mail radio button values

Tags: php, contact-form-7

I'm using `wpcf7_before_send_mail` with contact form 7 to capture form submissions and post contact details into a CRM. One of the forms *(Quote Form_Contact)* has radio buttons for "Account Manager". The options for this are 'Not Transfered' 'Agent.a' 'Agent.b' etc..

As not all forms include this field, I'm trying to check if $transfer exists and if so that it's value is not "Not Transferred" then append @domain.com to the end of the posted data to generate a valid agent's email address.

```
if ( 'Quote Form_Product' || 'Quote Form' == $title ) {

      $firstName = $posted_data['user_first_name'];
      $lastName = $posted_data['user_last_name'];
      $email= $posted_data['your-email'];
      $phone = $posted_data['your-number'];
      $message = $posted_data['your-message'];
      $bp = $posted_data['BP'][0];

    }

    if ( 'Quote Form_Contact' == $title ) {
      $firstName = $posted_data['user_first_name'];
      $lastName = $posted_data['user_last_name'];
      $email= $posted_data['your-email'];
      $phone = $posted_data['your-number'];
      $message = $posted_data['your-message'];
      $bp = $posted_data['BP'][0];
      $transfer = $posted_data['transfer'][0];
    }

     if(isset($transfer) && $transfer != 'Not Transferred'){
         $manager = $transfer.="@domain.com";
     } else {
         $manager = '';
     };
```

Currently submissions are returning no data for `$manager`

If I remove `isset($transfer) &&` from the code, submissions return the error "@domain.com is not a valid user" meaning that the value of the selected radio button hasn't been returned?

Can anyone advise on where I've gone wrong?

Comment: `if ( 'Quote Form_Product' || 'Quote Form' == $title )` - please go research why this is nonsense, and doesn’t work the way you think it does.

Comment: It would seem to have been working for the past 18 months or so? That being said, I didnt write the original code, I have just inherited it and need to make the change as outlined above.

Comment: `$manager = $transfer.="@doamin.com";` is also nonsense. This concatenates `@doamin.com` to `$transfer`, so if `$transfer` contained `foo` before, now you have `foo@doamin.com` as content of `$transfer`(!), and only then does this complete value get assigned to `$manager`. So any script that now looks for a match to the original checkbox value `foo` in `$transfer` won’t find one any more. Whoever wrote this doesn’t even seem to know PHP basics ...?

Comment: Having `foo@domain.com` as the value of `$transfer` to be submitted to the crm is what I'm trying to achieve... Not sure if I've misunderstood you there?